# Is there a command to get the name of the current day of the week?

Tags: datetime

I'm currently using `\date{\today}` to put the current date at the top of my document.  However, I would like the date to read "Friday, May 13, 2011" instead of just "May 13, 2011".  Is there a command to get the name of the current day of the week or something else I could use to do that?

**Edit**

Looks like the real problem I was having was that MikTeX was set to "ask me first" before downloading missing packages.  Apparently that setting doesn't work correctly in the version I have, so it was failing to download the datetime package.  I had to set it to download without asking to get it to work.

This solution also works, assuming the datetime package is actually installed:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{datetime}
\begin{document}
Today is \dayofweekname{\day}{\month}{\year}.
May 11, 2011 was \dayofweekname{11}{5}{2011}.    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\begin{document}
\datedayname
\end{document}
```

See the [datenumber package documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datenumber/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

In ConTeXt you can use

```
\currentdate[weekday]
```

To get the output that you want:

```
\currentdate[weekday,{, },month,{ },day,{, },year]
```